# HTML & CSS: Sticky as overlay

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create something like a calendar app but I'm having trouble with the layout.

I want to have a scrollable `div` with some timeline overlays.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1050px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(192, 244, 96, 0.658);
}

.main .middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main .middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 107, 49, 0.904);
}

.left {
  position: sticky;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;

  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: mediumvioletred
}

.items {
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: maroon;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae aspernatur eligendi dolorem perspiciatis nesciunt assumenda rem voluptas nam odit, modi optio quis dicta! Quibusdam, nisi qui porro laboriosam at eligendi! 
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="lines">
              <div class="line" style="top: 100px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 300px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 500px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 900px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 1000px;">Time</div>              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <div class="items">
              <div class="item" stlye="top: 300px"><div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to have `lines` as a overlay over the "calendar". But when I set `width: 100%;` to the `left` div, my `right` div gets pushed to the right.

I hope that makes any sense. Basically it should look like this, when calendar ist scrolled:

[image]
(I made this screenshot by scrolling to the right position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class names make no sense to me: `left` contains timeline and `right` contains items.

The code below makes what you described. I removed position `relative` from `right` to make it start from the left side and added `left: 0` on an item to move the item to the right place.

```css
.calendar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1050px;
  background-color: rosybrown;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(192, 244, 96, 0.658);
}

.main .middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.main .middle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 107, 49, 0.904);
}

.left {
  position: sticky;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;

  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  //position: relative;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: mediumvioletred
}

.items {
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: maroon;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae aspernatur eligendi dolorem perspiciatis nesciunt assumenda rem voluptas nam odit, modi optio quis dicta! Quibusdam, nisi qui porro laboriosam at eligendi! 
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="left">
            <div class="lines">
              <div class="line" style="top: 100px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 300px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 500px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 900px;">Time</div>
              <div class="line" style="top: 1000px;">Time</div>              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <div class="items">
              <div class="item" stlye="top: 300px"><div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. Yes the names are probably a mess. My CSS isn't very good as you can tell and I spend all day testing different stuff...

Comment: Nevermind it actually doesn't work as wanted because even when I set 'width: 100%' of `left` the lines do not have the complete width of the container